# RouterLink not working in child components

Tags: angular, router

I have a simple app with the following structure in my main app.html file.

```ts
    <navigation-list [unreadEmailCount]="unreadEmailCount| async"></navigation-list>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In my navigation-list component I can easily create routerLinks as follows:

```ts
<a routerLink="/starred" routerLinkActive='active'>link</a>
```

However, when I go into a component rendered within the router-outlet I cannot use routerLink. Using Router.route.nagive['path'] however, works. Any clues why this is?

EDIT:

App router module:

```ts
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {AuthGuard} from "./auth/auth-guard";
import {UnauthGuard} from "./auth/unauth-guard";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/inbox', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [UnauthGuard] }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  providers: [AuthGuard, UnauthGuard],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Photos router module (this is where the routerLink is not working)

```ts
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {PhotosComponent} from './photos/photos.component';
import { CreateAlbumComponent } from './album/create-album/create-album.component';
import { AlbumComponent } from './album/album/album.component'

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'photos',  component: PhotosComponent},
  { path: 'photos/:filter', component: PhotosComponent},
  { path: 'create-album', component: CreateAlbumComponent},
  { path: 'albums', component: AlbumComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})

export class PhotosRoutingModule {}
```

EDIT: photosModule:

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {PhotoListComponent} from "./photo-list/photo-list.component";
import {PhotosService} from './shared/photos.service';
import { PhotogroupListComponent } from './photogroup-list/photogroup-list.component';
import { PhotogroupItemComponent } from './photogroup-item/photogroup-item.component';
import { PhotosComponent } from './photos/photos.component';
import {FileUploadComponent} from "./shared/file-upload";
import {FileUploadService} from './shared/file-upload.service';
import { ImageSearchComponent } from './image-search/image-search.component';
import {ImageSearchService} from "./image-search/image-search.service";
import {AlbumSelectComponent} from './album/album-select.component';
import { AlbumSelectBarComponent } from './album/album-select-bar/album-select-bar.component';
import { CreateAlbumComponent } from './album/create-album/create-album.component';
import { CreateAlbumService } from './album/create-album/create-album.service';
import { AlbumService } from "./shared/album.service";
import { AlbumListComponent } from './album/album-list/album-list.component';
import { AlbumItemComponent } from './album/album-item/album-item.component';
import { AlbumComponent } from './album/album/album.component';
import { PhotoNavBarComponent } from './photo-nav-bar/photo-nav-bar.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    PhotoListComponent,
    PhotogroupListComponent,
    PhotogroupItemComponent,
    PhotosComponent,
    FileUploadComponent,
    ImageSearchComponent,
    AlbumSelectComponent,
    AlbumSelectBarComponent,
    CreateAlbumComponent,
    AlbumListComponent,
    AlbumItemComponent,
    AlbumComponent,
    PhotoNavBarComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    PhotosService,
    FileUploadService,
    ImageSearchService,
    CreateAlbumService,
    AlbumService
  ]
})

export class PhotosModule { }

export {PhotosService, FileUploadService, ImageSearchService, CreateAlbumService, AlbumService}
```

Comment: Add your Route configuration, also have you added `<router-outlet>` in your child component, add its code as well to help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added the router modules above

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If the child component is from a different module then you need to ensure this module has `RouterModule` in `imports`

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  declarations: [NavigationListComponent],
  exports: [NavigationListComponent],
})
export class SomeSharedModule{}
```

Comment: I edited with both Router modules above. From what I can see they're already included but I might be missing something

Comment: What does "cannot use routerLink" mean exactly?

Comment: It means that this code  <a routerLink="/photos">link</a> does not even evaluate to a link (i.e. cursor doesn't change to pointer) and nothing happens when I click it

Comment: But you don't get any errors in the browser console? This behavior indicates that the `routerOutlet` directive is not known, which should be fixed by my answer  :-/

Comment: What NgModule belongs the `NavigationList` component to?

Comment: The NavigationList belongs to the appModule (the core module) while the component containing the broken routerLink belongs to the photoModule that's imported into the appModule. I've added my photoModule code in my questions now as well. The console doesn't show any errors

Comment: That module is missing the `RouterModule` imports. `RouterModule` contains the `RouterLink` directive. You need to add all modules to imports if you use directives, components, or pipes from these imports. Only for services it's enough to import the module once to make the available globally.

Comment: Glad to hear :)